# CreatedAtRoute passing multiple route values

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I'm attempting to create an endpoint (POST) that accepts 1 or more models which will then be bulk inserted into the DB.

Everything is fine except when I attempt to call `CreatedAtRoute` with lists of the created objects and routes.

When I call `CreatedAtRoute` with multiple routes/models I get a runtime `InvalidOperationException`, no matching routes.

#### Example

```
[HttpPost]
 public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<QaiStateModel>>> CreateQaiStateAsync( 
        IEnumerable<QaiStateCreationModel> inputQaiStates )
 {            
     var qaiStates = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<QaiState>>( inputQaiStates );
     await _qaiService.AddQaiStatesAsync( qaiState ).ConfigureAwait( false );

     var models = _mapper.Map<List<QaiStateModel>>( qaiState );

     var ids = models.Select( m => new { qaiStateID = m.ID } );
     return CreatedAtRoute( "GetQaiState", ids, models );
}
```

For reference I do have the following `GET/{ID}` endpoint:

```
[HttpGet( "{qaiStateID}", Name = "GetQaiState" )]
public async Task<ActionResult<QaiStateModel>> GetQaiStateAsync( int qaiStateID )
```

### Question

Is it possible to return both `URI`'s to access the newly added resources as well as a list of the model representation of those resources?

I'm also unsure if this is the correct way to handle this situation (in regards to what I should be returning).

Comment: CreatedAtRoute implies one resource <-> one route. You will probably need to return the status code and instantiate the object manually

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Yeah I figured that would be the case. Is what I’m trying to do (bulk inserting) an unusual use case for a REST API?

Comment: It's not at all unusual, but REST is for dealing with a resource (not resources) so you have to break out of the pattern a bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `CreatedAtRoute` like below:

```
return CreatedAtRoute("GetQaiState", new { qaiStateID = ids },models);
```

Change `GetQaiStateAsync` method like below:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<QaiStateModel>> GetQaiStateAsync(List<int> qaiStateID )
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to populate the location header of the 201 response, return the created models and pass the ID's via the route I had to do the following:

1. Create a new `GET` handler that expects an array of ID's
2. Create a `ModelBinder` that converts the passed array of ID's from the route
3. Point the `POST` handlers `CreatedAtRoute` to point to this `GET` handler. Furthermore the newly created `ID's` had to be concatenated in to a comma separated list which gets passed to `CreatedAtRoute`

### Step 1:

The `GET` handler now expects an `array` of ID's to be passed via the route. Note the specified route `({ids})`. Here I'm specifying I want an array of values delimited with parenthesis `()`.

```
[HttpGet( "({ids})", Name = "GetQaiStateCollection" )]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<QaiStateModel>>> GetQaiStateCollectionAsync( 
        [FromRoute]
        [ModelBinder( BinderType = typeof( ArrayModelBinder ) )]
        IEnumerable<int>? ids )
{
    if ( ids is null )
        return BadRequest( "Invalid ID's" );

    var states = await _qaiService
        .GetQaiStatesAsync( ids ).ConfigureAwait( false );

    if ( ids.Count( ) != states.Count( ) )
        return NotFound( "Failed to find one or more states matching the provided ID's" );

    var models = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<QaiStateModel>>( states );
    return Ok( models );
}
```

### Step 2:

In order to convert the route `http://localhost:32003/QaiStateCollection/(4,2,3)` into a `IEnumerable<int>` a custom model binder had to be created.

```
public class ArrayModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync( ModelBindingContext bindingContext )
    {
        // This model binder only works for enumerable types.
        if ( !bindingContext.ModelMetadata.IsEnumerableType )
        {
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Failed( );
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        // Get the input value via the value provider.
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider
            .GetValue( bindingContext.ModelName ).ToString( );
        
        if ( string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( value ) )
        {
            // Returning null here will allow us to check for this
            // and return a bad request.
            bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success( null );
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        var elementType = bindingContext.ModelType.GenericTypeArguments.First( );
        var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter( elementType );
        
        var values = value.Split( new [ ] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries )
            .Select( v => converter.ConvertFromString( v.Trim( ) ) )
            .ToArray( );

        var typedValues = Array.CreateInstance( elementType, values.Length );
        values.CopyTo( typedValues, 0 );
        bindingContext.Model = typedValues;

        bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success( bindingContext.Model );
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

### Step 3:

Here the ID's are concatenated into a comma separated list and passed to the `CreatedAtRoute`. The new `GET` handler name is also passed to `CreatedAtRoute`.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<QaiStateModel>>> CreateQaiStateCollectionAsync( 
           IEnumerable<QaiStateCreationModel> inputModels )
{            
    var qaiStates = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<QaiState>>( inputModels );
    await _qaiService.AddQaiStateCollectionAsync( qaiStates ).ConfigureAwait( false );

    var models = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<QaiStateModel>>( qaiStates );
    var ids = string.Join( ",", models.Select( m => m.ID ) );

    return CreatedAtRoute( "GetQaiStateCollection", new { ids }, models );
}
```

Comment: emmm I think your custom model binding is a bit complex for your requirement.Why not trying my solution below?

Comment: @Rena Because I have another controller which has a similar requirement except that the ID's are `Guid`'s. Your solution wont work for that. That being said I didn't specify that as a requirement so that is no fault of yours.

Comment: Let me check. :)

Comment: @Rena You should receive an `InvalidOperationException` if I remember correctly. I'll still accept your answer as it directly answered my original question.

Comment: Hi @WBuck,I have checked it in my project.It worked well.emmmm,maybe any other things missing in your project.I used asp.net core 3.1.You could check the gif:https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSQIl.gif

Comment: @Rena ahhhhhh I see whats happening here. You're passing the ID's via the body while I'm passing them via the route. Thats why you're not seeing the issue. Try passing your ID's via the route instead.